# You are being redirected. rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I created simple scaffold, it has the destroy method with

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :action => "index", :status => 302  }
  format.json { head :ok }
end
```

end

when I click "Destroy", I see the page with words "You are being redirected." where word "redirected" is link to the posts_path. what should i do to fix this bug?

Comment: Why are you giving it a 302 status? That might help answer. I'm not clear, though ... on exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, if I were the asker, I'd be asking why rails is sending html with a "you are being redirected" message, instead of actually sending  an HTTP redirect header -- or why the browser is displaying 'you are being redireted' instead of just, you know, redirecting. Are you suggesting that status 302 somehow makes this happen where whatever rails default status for redirect_to is would not. Why is that?

Comment: I had the same issue. In the end I found out that I accidentally have overwritten a method in the rails framework. As soon I renamed the method, the issue was solved. Here is a more detailed description: http://robert-reiz.com/2012/07/20/rails-3-x-you-are-being-redirected-406-not-acceptable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pull out the `:status => 302' option and double check that my Destroy link has`:method => 'delete'`set. If the`:method` isn't set on the link then you will be redirected to your index action.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. I am have the same issue. I played around with status code 302 and 301 but thats' all the same result for me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I found the comment from Robert Reiz on the question helped me solve the same issue. I use the gem `decent_exposure`, and I had a model called `Location`. In the controller, `expose(:location)` creates a method that breaks the redirect. `Location` is now `Place`.

Comment: I too have a model called location and having the same issues. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Send proper status code:

```
redirect_to root_path, notice: SUCCESS_MSG, status: :found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx with rails. Add the config below to nginx.

```
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
```