# "You are being redirected" page in Rails 3 after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I hope you can help me with this.
I have an 'update' method in my controller, at the end of this method I have:

```
redirect_to :action => 'index'
```

Where 'index' is a method on the same controller.
This takes me to the infamous 'You are being redirected page', which is weird because I'm actually getting a 302 response.

Comment: I have the same issue. After a redirect I get the "You are being redirected page".

Comment: I am even getting this error page in production then I use the "enforce_ssl" filter. Everytime the enforce_ssl filter should redirect to https I am getting a "You are being redirected page'.

Comment: I had the same issue. In the end I found out that I accidentally have overwritten a method in the rails framework. As soon I renamed the method, the issue was solved. Here is a more detailed description: http://robert-reiz.com/2012/07/20/rails-3-x-you-are-being-redirected-406-not-acceptable/

Comment: It might be due to your web server, like nginx. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338726/you-are-being-redirected-rails-3-1/17258229#17258229

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses HTTP status code 302 (temporary redirect) when you call redirect_to.If you’d like to use a different status code (301 for permanent redirect), you can do so by using the :status option:

```
redirect_to :action => 'index' , :status => 301
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already tried that, but it still sends me to the 'You are being redirected page'

Answer (score 0):

Just use return after that line like this

```
redirect_to :action => 'index' 
return
```